# How to change cell color in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I am trying to change a cell color in my data table base on the value which is present and absent . i used button to populate my data table based in my database, 
i have 53 columns (week 1 to week 53 + name).

Comment: DefaultCellStyle?

Comment: What have you tried?  Surely Google would have turned up many hits regarding the styling of a data grid or whatever control you are using.

Comment: Please specify the exact type of control type(DataGridView,DataGrid,Another control maybe)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes i've tried almost every top answers in google and it didn't answer my question.

Comment: @YasharAliabasi i used datagridview, i don;t know how would i use array in this kind of problem although array would be my best solution here.

Comment: A DataTable obviously doesn't have a color as it isn't a visual thing. You need to pay much more attention the the details of what you do and clearly tell us about it. Had you done that, eg googled 'DataGridView Cell Color' you woudl have found the solution easily.

Comment: @TaW datagridview  sorry about that.

Comment: what i want to do is once click my button (basically it will populate my datagridview based in my database) and in every column from week 1 to week 53 that has a "PRESENT" value that specific cell will be colored GREEN and if it is "ABSENT" it will be colored RED.

Comment: If you tried something and it didn't work, then **show what you tried**!  Then we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) and make your decision there:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 0 && YourCondition)e.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Will it work for all of my cells? i am having doubts (tho i haven't tried it yet) that all of the columns or rows will be colored in green or red. and not the specific cell only. for example. in my week 1 i have this

name     | week1 | week2|
myname| present|absent|

that cell with "present" as value will be colored green and the week 2 with "absent" as value will be colored red

Comment: Yes you can check you cell by `e.ColumnIndex` as I added to `if` condition

Comment: would you help me throughout this ?. as i dont have any information on how does this work. my professor only told us how to populate datagrid and thats it.

Comment: i dont know that will i put in that "yourcondition"

Comment: What is the type of present and absent in database?

Comment: it is a varchar.

Comment: What will happen to these columns when someone become absent and present.That is your condition.

Comment: that specific CELL which have a "PRESENT" value will be colored green. without altering the whole column or rows. the thing here is that i have 50+ names and each of them will be monitored for their attendance. thats why i need only the specific cell to be colored by their value.

Comment: If Present column index was 4 then you can say `if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "PRESENT" && e.ColumnIndex == 4)`

Comment: i got this error

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SCAN ATTENDANCE MONITORING.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This question is not related to your main question and I've already answered your questions.If my answers helped you then accept it.

Comment: it worked YES tho i cant figure out how that code works. if you could enumerate me how each piece of the code it will answer my question completely but still thankyou for your help cheers

Comment: i think i need to copy paste it 53 times. for each columns and cells. am i right??

Comment: i tried to use catch exception. and all of my cells was colored RED

Answer (score 0):

```
  try
                {
                    if (e.Value != null)
                    {
                        // Check for the string "pink" in the cell.
                        string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
                        stringValue = stringValue.ToUpper();
                        if ((stringValue.IndexOf("PRESENT") > -1))
                        {
                            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
```

Comment: i used this code and all i need to do is to repeat it 50 times